# How do I stop false GPIO triggers from occuring?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new to interacting with Raspberry Pi's and have a Pi that I am using to send a webhook so that I may be alerted when someone presses a button I have stationed as a sort of door bell. I have the webhook all sorted out, but I keep getting false GPIO triggers that send me the hook when the button has done nothing.

I tried eliminating noise by using shielded wire, only using about 12" or so of wire between the Raspberry Pi and the button, and even including a Resistor-Capacitor circuit to the loop as an attempt to "hardware debounce" the button. Even after those upgrades, I see the false button presses, albeit far far fewer (once every few weeks, instead of once every few days).

The code I am using

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import sys
import os

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)


buttonPin = 16

input_state1 = True
last_state1 = True


GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

try:
    while True:
        input_state1 = GPIO.input(16)
        if input_state1 != last_state1:
            os.system('python hook.py')
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I expect to see no false button presses, especially since I am already using the internal pull up and the hardware loop as well. I am just lost at this point

Comment: is the indentation just a copy paste error?

Comment: Appeared to be so. I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

last_state1 is never updated, therefore when input_state1 changes, your `if input_state1 != last_state1:` condition is going to be true, and it's going to trigger `os.system('python hook.py')` over and over in the while loop.

Solution is to set the `last_state1 = input_state1` after the `os.system` call.

Comment: I assume then that `GPIO.cleanup()` does not stop the loop like I thought it would?

Comment: yes, the `finally:` block won't be called until the while loop is exited.

Comment: This resulted in a double webhook trigger. I am unsure if the false alarms will go away with this since they happen maybe once a month. Time should tell, though

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the wire is actually firing intermittently. Raspberry Pis are cheap hardware, not exactly the most reliable things. It's possible that it's reacting due to noise on its input power supply. You already added hardware debounce, how did you decide the resistor capacitor values? Tweaking those might change the behavior.

In any case, I would complement your hardware debounce with software debounce.

```py
import time

try:
    while True:
        if not GPIO.input(16):
            time.sleep(0.1)  # some hysteresis
            # check the pin again, this way, it will only fire the hook if the button
            # has been held down for over 0.1 seconds
            if not GPIO.input(16):
                os.system('python hook.py')
        time.sleep(0.1)  # give your pi a break every once in a while
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I wrote the above assuming you want the button to be active-low. If you want active-high, remove the `not`s.